# Error when adding a new field to database context

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am programming an MVC 4 ASP.NET application. I keep getting this error when I want to add a new field to the database:

```
The model backing the 'UsersContext' context 
has changed since the database was created.
Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database.
```

What should I do?

Comment: instead of paste code ...and write error.....

Comment: Have you considered using Code First Migrations to update the database?

Comment: No, how can i do that? will it fix it? Thanks

Comment: Yes it will because your local model is not the same as the model defined in the database. CFM will update the table definition in such a way that they are compatible. Did you bother to read your error message?

Comment: I am a beginner in this, and this is my 5th day working non-stop on it, yes i did read the error message, tried many things but they mostly didnt work with me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because your database is no longer in sync with your DbContext classes.

You should look into using `migrations`

You work with code first migrations using the Package Management Console.

```
enable-migrations
```

Does exactly what the name implies. Initializes migrations in your project. This will create a folder inside your project and generate the files needed.

```
add-migration InitialCreate
```

This creates a migration. InitialCreate is actually a string and you can change it to whatever you want. This command will generate the scripts needed to create the database from strach.

```
update-database
```

This command verifies the database and applies the migration (or migrations - there can be multiple) required in order to get the database up-to-date.

This is the initial setup. If you do further changes to your first code first classes, or add more, you will just have to add a new migration and then execute it.

```
add-migration AddedFirstName
update-database
```

It's that simple!

There are some more advanced concepts like seed, rollback, update to specific migration, etc., but what I have typed above covers the basics and the day to day usage of migrations.

I recommend you to read this article which explains everything in much more detail:  http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Consider stating up front that `DbContext` relates to Entity Framework (as indicated by the link that you included at the end). The OP didn't appear to be aware of this. (Note that I added the 'entity-framework' tag to the question.)